# Index minio Documents Using Elastic-Search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, minio

Can someone tell me what approach I should follow to index documents stored in Minio bucket using elastic-search so that it enables me to search the documents using specific keywords.

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin in elastic search ingest-attachment is used to index any document follow the link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html